# What is the Academy for, and how do I use it?

Tags: heroville

I just bought the Academy Blueprints, and a new table has appeared on my Upgrades tab, but there's no indication of how to use it. It looks like I should be able to send my heroes there somehow, but there isn't a new profession option for them.

What is the Academy for and how do I use it?

Comment: I can confirm that when a hero hits level 11, they become eligible for the Academy.  As for what it does, still not sure.

Comment: @Batophobia Yeah, I got a hero to level 11, they appeared in the list with two options: worker or adventurer. I selected adventurer and they went away again. No idea what that did.

Comment: I just noticed that someone I set to be a "worker" is gaining experience from gathering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your hero hits level 11 they get plopped into the academy. They will still continue what they are currently tasked with, just also in the academy.

When in the academy you select 1 of 2 jobs (or leave them as "free").

- Worker - they are *permanent* workers (you can't send them adventuring), but gain exp while working and are more efficient at it
- Adventurer - they become *permanent* adventurers (can't employ them), and they gain boosted exp and are *much* better at adventuring.

**EDIT**: It seems there is a bug with the academy. heroes I "graduate" to workers would sometimes still be able to go adventuring, especially on refreshing the page... all but one heroes became "free".

Comment: I can still send workers adventuring and vice versa.

Comment: Really? I trained a worker in the academy and whenever I would try send him adventuring he would instantly return to work. same went for trying to employ a dedicated adventurer

Comment: I can confirm that Workers get XP after Academy training.  Also, when I try to set a trained "Worker" to "Adventure", they are immediately sent back and flagged as "Gather".  However, a trained "Adventure" could still be employed into the workers.